# Is there a way to show NavigationRailDestinations at the bottom of the NavigationRail?

Tags: flutter, dart

I added a NavigationRail to my app but i want to show the icons at the bottom left the column. Is it possible to do that? I tried MainAxisAlignment and CrossAxisAlignment but could not manage.
I saw some posts stating that this could only be achieved with a custom Navigation Rail. Is it correct?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDesktopBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDesktopBody({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyDesktopBody> createState() => _MyDesktopBodyState();
}

class _MyDesktopBodyState extends State<MyDesktopBody> {
  NavigationRailLabelType labelType = NavigationRailLabelType.all;

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("BDK Akademi"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            NavigationRail(
              onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedIndex = value;
                  },
                );
              },
              destinations: [
                NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: Text("Anasayfa")),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.text_snippet_sharp),
                    label: Text("Instagram Eğitimi")),
                NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_box), label: Text("Hesabım")),
              ],
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupAlignment: 1.0`

> {double? groupAlignment}
>
> The vertical alignment for the group of [destinations] within the rail.

> The value must be between -1.0 and 1.0.
>
> If [groupAlignment] is -1.0, then the items are aligned to the top. If
> [groupAlignment] is 0.0, then the items are aligned to the center. If
> [groupAlignment] is 1.0, then the items are aligned to the bottom.
>
> The default is -1.0.